# Is it possible to interact with automation studio using REST APIs

Tags: rest-api, soap-api, dataextensions, automationstudio

I'm a .net developer and trying to grasp knowledge of Salesforce marketing cloud REST API's for my new project.

We have an automation created in sf, after loading data into Data Extension, I want to trigger this automation process.

Is it possible to interact with Automation Studio using REST APIs? I see the following documentation to work with Automation studio [Interact with Automation Studio](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/interacting_with_automation_studio_via_the_web_service_soap_api.htm). Is it possible to perform the same using REST API?

Answer (score 1):

No, not as of yet unfortunately.
You can use SOAP or FuelSDK